# How to define derived List with methods and populate them in C#

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have the class `Columns` which is derived from `List<Column>`. I want to populate the class inside one of its methods named `GetColumns()`. But I'm having trouble doing this.  Maybe I'm missing something very very obvious here.

What I'm trying to do is to define `Collections` as classes that derive from `List and I want to extend these classes to populate them and other stuff.

```
public class Columns : List<Column>
{        
    public void GetColumns()
    {`
        this = Building.PColumns;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail. What exactly behaved different from expectation?

Comment: @Codor It says that this expression can't be used as an assignment target.

Comment: Inside a class, the `this` reference cannot be reassigned. What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you mean `return Building.PColumns`?

Comment: @Codor I want to create `Collections` with Custom methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to `this` in a class. (You could do so in a `struct`.)

Instead of:

```
this = Building.PColumns;
```

Try:

```
this.Clear();
this.AddRange(Building.PColumns);
```

Comment: I was willing to use LINQ to, for example. `var columns = Building.PColumns.Where(...)`, so with your method I'll be able to assign the columns to the class using `AddRange`. I was wondering if this is the correct procedure? Cause I read somewhere that we shouldn't derive from List<T>.

Comment: @Vahid I can't know the reason you needed to derive from `List<string>` since I don't know the rest of your code. However, if you can get away with using linq, you should do so. Simpler that away. I wouldn't say you should _never_ derive from `List<T>` though.  There may be circumstances it is necessary. However, generally, I would prefer [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Thanks Eren, I was just reading about that. I guess I won't derive then.

Answer (score 1):

If you're extending List you should just be able to call all the usual methods ie (add, addrange, remove etc..). Personally I would either extend IEnumerable or use Columns as a wrapper class with a member of type List but each to their own and it of course depends on what you're doing. Especially since you know the type of the list beforehand and you're handling the login in internal functions anyway, i would just have it as a member.

Answer (score 1):

Change the body of the method `GetColumns`. It is a bit unclear where `Building.PColumns` is defined. In neither case the `this` pointer can be reassigned. Furthermore, the name `GetColumns` suggests that something is returned. However this is not the case as its return type is `void`. Change the return type of `GetColumns` to the type of `Building.PColumns` and return `Building.PColumns`.